# Follow links to end in Scrapy tutorials

Tags: scrapy

Not sure if this is the correct place to ask such a general question.

But, I can't seem to find any examples or tutorials using Scrapy to scrape a website by following links to an end page which would then have the product details which I wish to extract information from for that product.

So I start from the main web page where I can scrape the  tags for the href, but how do I then follow each link, which would take me to another page which will have more  href links which, if I follow again will then ultimately take me to the product info itself where the data I want to extract resides

Is this some kind of recursion? Sorry, but I am new to this. So does anyone know of a good tutorial/ example? I find it a bit difficult to follow the official documentation.

Comment: This spider may help you: https://github.com/scrapinghub/scrapy-training/blob/master/unit2/spiders/spider_2_authors_details.py

Comment: Also, the lesson 5 in this tutorial covers what you need: https://learn.scrapinghub.com/scrapy/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a couple of examples here: https://github.com/scrapy/quotesbot

Also, here is an example to parse books on http://books.toscrape.com/ :

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


class MySpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = 'toscrape.com'
    start_urls = ['http://books.toscrape.com/']

    rules = (
        # The links that matches the allow / deny arguments will be processed in parse_book.
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('/catalogue/',), deny=('/category/', '/page')), callback='parse_book'),

        # These links will be processed in the CrawlSpider defaut callback that will look for new links.
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('/page',))),
    )

    def parse_book(self, response):

        yield {
            'title': response.css('div.product_main>h1::text').extract_first(),
            'price': response.css('p.price_color::text').extract_first(),
        }
```

When you use a `CrawlSpider` like in this example, scrapy does automatically extracts the links for you and iterates though each of them until no more can be found.

Comment: Thanks for this. I will try this out when I get a chance and report back.

Answer (score 0):

I used the Scrapy documentation to do this.

You can see my example I have here;

https://github.com/dbaleeds/ScrapyQuoteExtractor/blob/master/quotes/spiders/quotesBrainy.py

This is same thing you are trying to do, reading links from a page, following the link then reading in the data from the result pages.

```
def parse(self, response):
```

Reads the links page.

```
def parse_item(self, response):
```

Parses the data within in page, from the link it followed above.

I would suggest to implement this to see how it works then use this as a base to build your own project with.

Comment: Does this mean that for each level I will need to add another "def parse(self, response)" method? So if the final data is 4 links deep I will need 4 methods, the final one being the parsing of each item?

Comment: Yes correct. Or you can use Crawl spider as the poster mentioned to set regex rules to crawl to any depth: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider